# Download zip file from rails 4 to angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to download a zip file, sent from a rails 4 application to the front-end.

The zip file construction is working correctly, I can unzip the file and get the content

```
filename = "cvs_job_#{params[:job_id]}.zip"
archive_path ="#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{filename}"
File.delete(archive_path) if File.exists?(archive_path)
Zip::File.open(archive_path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  params[:user_ids].each do |user_id|
    user = User.find(user_id)
    zipfile.add("#{user.last_name}_#{user.first_name}.pdf", user.cv_file.path) unless user.cv_file.nil?
  end
end
send_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{filename}", :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment')
```

but how am I supposed to handle the response back in the promise?

```
  $http(req).success(function(success){
    console.log(success)
  })
```

I saw the zip file in the chrome console, such as :

```
"...8f�~��/g6�I�-v��=� ..."
```

I have tried many solutions but none are working.

I thought that I would be able to send the file and download from my front.

Comment: "I have tried many solutions but none are working." could you provide what solutions you have tried?

Comment: Well, I tried to put my file in the public directory and send the link as a response. I used a hidden element to be able to click on it. But it wasn't successful

Comment: the file look corrupted